# R prediction of filler values (needed to generate smoothed curve from model)

Tags: r, ggplot2, model, predict, nls

I am trying to use `predict()` filler values (the rows contain x values and y values as `NaN`) to fill in the prediction curve in a plot that includes the data.  The idea is to get a smoother prediction curve than just by using the data x values.  However, `predict()` is returning funky values that do seem to not be a `y` calculation based on the `x` value.  The questions are:

- What is wrong with the prediction calculation.
- How do I set the dataframe or change the code to get the smoothed line.

This is what the output looks like (note the dips for the erroneously predicted y values):
[image: erroneously predicted values for least squares non-linear regression]

Here is the code that yields the gruesome result:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(nlme)

# generate test data frame
x = c(0, 5, 100, 1000, 50, 200, 300, 500)
y = c(0, 3, 5, 6, NaN, NaN, NaN, NaN)
df=data.frame(x,y)


# a log model to fit the data
lF <- formula(y ~ Ymax-(Ymax-Y0)*exp(-k*x))

# nonlinear regression
model <- nls(lF, data=df,
             start=list(Ymax=3.0, k=0.01, Y0=0.3),
             na.action = na.omit)

# print out the model resutls
summary(model)

# Derive predicted lines
df$pred <- predict(model)

# plot the data and three models
ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+
     geom_point() +
     geom_line(aes(y=pred))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specificy the argument `newdata=df` in the `prediction` command, you get:

```
df$pred <- predict(model, newdata=df)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+
     geom_point(color="red", size=3) +
     geom_line(aes(y=pred), size=1) +
     theme_bw()
```

[image]

If you want to draw a smooth line from the model, you need to define a suitable sequence of `x` values:

```
df2 <- data.frame(x=c(seq(0,1,0.001),1:1000))
df2$pred <- predict(model, newdata=df2)

ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y))+
     geom_point(color="red", size=3) +
     geom_line(data=df2, aes(x=x, y=pred), color="blue", size=1) +
     theme_bw()
```

[image]

Comment: Marco, was this suppose to work for a lmer model? df$pred <- predict(model, newdata=df) appears to not work. Thank you

Comment: @jtjtjtjt Nice question. Please, create a new question on SO and I will try to answer.

Comment: Posted here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74279784/r-visualizing-predict-of-a-mixed-effects-model-with-a-spline Thanks