# R: Visualizing predict() of a mixed-effects model with a spline

Tags: r, mixed-models, spline

I was trying to [replicate this post,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62366107/19595763) in order to visualize the model, but now on a lmer model with a spline.

```
m9 <-  lmer(r  ~ lspline(MINUTES, knots = c(5)) +  ( 1 | ID) , data = dat )
summary(m9)



df$pred <- predict(m9, newdata=df)
```

Sadly, it seems it doesn't work.

Is it possible to achieve the same result?

data below:

```r
dat <- structure(list(r = c(61, 93, 92, 90, 88, 87, 85, 83, 105, 106, 
                              107, 107, 107, 104, 87, 103, 96, 92, 88, 84, 84, 56, 87, 82, 
                              82, 81, 82, 78, 74, 118, 115, 112, 108, 105, 102, 69, 81, 78, 
                              73, 72, 70, 71, 88, 111, 104, 105, 104, 103, 97, 80, 99, 94, 
                              96, 96, 92, 93, 76, 104, 100, 102, 100, 95, 95, 66, 91, 87, 83, 
                              83, 80, 77, 90, 100, 95, 92, 90, 89, 84, 86, 91, 90, 89, 86, 
                              88, 87, 64, 89, 85, 82, 80, 80, 77, 59, 86, 80, 78, 79, 79, 77, 
                              82, 113, 110, 112, 109, 106, 110, 65, 93, 88, 87, 87, 84, 67, 
                              87, 111, 102, 106, 103, 99, 99, 69, 97, 94, 92, 90, 88, 88, 75, 
                              89, 84, 82, 80, 79, 77, 83, 103, 101, 98, 97, 96, 97, 73, 111, 
                              90, 86, 100, 91, 95, 72, 102, 97, 96, 96, 97, 96, 71, 83, 84, 
                              82, 84, 82, 83, 96, 93, 90, 89, 89, 95, 92, 117, 115, 112, 110, 
                              111, 112, 63, 100, 95, 96, 93, 91, 92, 64, 74, 73, 71, 71, 70, 
                              85, 67, 105, 103, 99, 96, 95, 98, 74, 105, 100, 102, 88, 99, 
                              100, 54, 81, 78, 75, 80, 75, 77, 102, 112, 105, 102, 98, 95, 
                              90, 79, 102, 99, 98, 92, 95, 90), MINUTES = c(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 
                                                                            25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 
                                                                            5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 
                                                                            20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 
                                                                            0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 
                                                                            15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 
                                                                            30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 
                                                                            10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 
                                                                            25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 
                                                                            5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 
                                                                            20, 25, 30, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 
                                                                            0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 
                                                                            15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 
                                                                            30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30), ID = c(1, 
                                                                                                                                            1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11, 11, 11, 11, 
                                                                                                                                            11, 11, 11, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 
                                                                                                                                            13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 
                                                                                                                                            16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 
                                                                                                                                            18, 18, 18, 18, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
                                                                                                                                            4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 40, 41, 41, 41, 41, 
                                                                                                                                            41, 41, 41, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 42, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 43, 
                                                                                                                                            43, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 44, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 46, 
                                                                                                                                            46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 46, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 49, 5, 5, 5, 
                                                                                                                                            5, 5, 5, 5, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 52, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 53, 
                                                                                                                                            54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 54, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 55, 56, 56, 
                                                                                                                                            56, 56, 56, 56, 56, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 57, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
                                                                                                                                            6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 
                                                                                                                                            9, 9)), row.names = c(8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 14L, 22L, 23L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  24L, 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L, 41L, 42L, 43L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  44L, 45L, 46L, 47L, 48L, 49L, 50L, 51L, 52L, 53L, 54L, 55L, 56L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  64L, 65L, 66L, 67L, 68L, 69L, 70L, 78L, 79L, 80L, 81L, 82L, 83L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  84L, 85L, 86L, 87L, 88L, 89L, 90L, 91L, 99L, 100L, 101L, 102L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  103L, 104L, 105L, 106L, 107L, 108L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 120L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  121L, 122L, 123L, 124L, 125L, 126L, 134L, 135L, 136L, 137L, 138L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  139L, 140L, 148L, 149L, 150L, 151L, 152L, 153L, 154L, 155L, 156L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  157L, 158L, 159L, 160L, 161L, 162L, 163L, 164L, 165L, 166L, 167L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  168L, 169L, 170L, 171L, 172L, 173L, 174L, 175L, 176L, 177L, 178L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  179L, 180L, 181L, 182L, 183L, 184L, 185L, 186L, 187L, 188L, 189L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  190L, 191L, 192L, 193L, 194L, 195L, 196L, 197L, 198L, 199L, 200L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  201L, 202L, 203L, 204L, 205L, 206L, 207L, 208L, 209L, 210L, 218L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  219L, 220L, 221L, 222L, 223L, 224L, 225L, 226L, 227L, 228L, 229L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  230L, 231L, 232L, 233L, 234L, 235L, 236L, 237L, 238L, 239L, 240L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  241L, 242L, 243L, 244L, 245L, 246L, 247L, 248L, 249L, 250L, 251L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  252L, 253L, 254L, 255L, 256L, 257L, 258L, 259L, 260L, 261L, 262L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  263L, 264L, 265L, 273L, 274L, 275L, 276L, 277L, 278L, 279L, 287L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  288L, 289L, 290L, 291L, 292L, 293L, 294L, 295L, 296L, 297L, 298L, 
                                                                                                                                                                  299L, 300L, 308L, 309L, 310L, 311L, 312L, 313L, 314L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: where/what package is `lspline()` from?

Comment: @BenBolker looks like there is an `lspline` package which contains the function.

Comment: Also, can you be more explicit about what "didn't work" means? Did you get an error, warning, undesired output, ... ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The type of spline you are using appears to fit a piecewise linear model rather than a smooth curve. Presumably that's what you wanted.

If you want to predict the whole data set, you can either do it with or without the random effects.

First, with:

```r
library(lme4)
library(lspline)

m9 <-  lmer(r  ~ lspline(MINUTES, knots = c(5)) +  ( 1 | ID) , 
            data = dat )

df <- data.frame(MINUTES = rep(0:30, length(unique(dat$ID))),
                 ID = rep(unique(dat$ID), each = 31))

df$predict <- predict(m9, newdata = df)

ggplot(df, aes(MINUTES, predict, color = factor(ID))) +
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(y = r)) +
  guides(color = guide_none())
```

[image]

Second, without:

```r
df$predict <- predict(m9, newdata = df, re.form = NA)

ggplot(df[1:31,], aes(MINUTES, predict, color = factor(ID))) +
  geom_line(color = 'black') +
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(y = r)) +
  guides(color = guide_none())
```

[image]

If you were actually looking for a smoothed fit using splines, then you could do something like:

```r
m9 <-  lmer(r  ~ splines::bs(MINUTES, knots = c(5)) +  ( 1 | ID) , 
            data = dat )

df <- data.frame(MINUTES = rep(seq(0, 30, 0.1), length(unique(dat$ID))),
                 ID = rep(unique(dat$ID), each = 301))

df$predict <- predict(m9, newdata = df, re.form = NA)

ggplot(df[1:301,], aes(MINUTES, predict, color = factor(ID))) +
  geom_line(color = 'black', linetype = 2) +
  geom_point(data = dat, aes(y = r)) +
  guides(color = guide_none())
```

[image]

Comment: Ben it gave this message "Error in rep(0, nobs) : invalid 'times' argument"

Comment: Allan, that looks great. Thanks a lot. lspline had slightly better fit than all other splines available in "splines" package. That was the main reason to use that one.

Comment: Actually I have a follow-up question. Is it possible to add a 95CI or SE to the line? I tried with df$predict <- predict(m9, newdata = df,   re.form = NA,  interval = 'confidence'), but it gave a Warning message:
In predict.merMod(m9, newdata = df, re.form = NA, interval = "confidence") :
  unused arguments ignored

Answer (score 2):

To get predictions with confidence intervals, you should use one of the add-on packages (`emmeans`, `effects`, `ggeffects`, etc.) that can compute confidence intervals for `lmer` models (note that these CIs are conditioned on the random effects estimates, i.e. they take account *only* of uncertainty in the fixed-effect coefficient estimates; should you want to see how these calculations work, or build them for yourself, see [the relevant section of the GLMM FAQ](https://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#predictions-andor-confidence-or-prediction-intervals-on-predictions)):

```r
library(ggeffects)
pdat <- ggpredict(m9)
ggplot(dat, aes(MINUTES)) +
    geom_point(aes(y = r, color = factor(ID))) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    geom_line(data = pdat$MINUTES, aes(x = x, y = predicted)) +
    geom_ribbon(data = pdat$MINUTES, aes(x = x, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), alpha = 0.2)
```

[image]